# How to get git log --oneline --graph with chronological commits/merges between branches?

Tags: git, logging, git-log

For now I have the following alias (found somewhere on the internet):

```
[alias]
  lg = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all
```

but this will produce something like that in my repo:

```
* a18c363 - (2 weeks ago) Fix | Changed sed separator - Patryk (wierd_branch)
* 7c6ddd8 - (2 weeks ago) Feature  - Patryk 
* 2bd909b - (2 weeks ago) Fix | This was not supposed to be there.... - Patryk 
* a99f925 - (2 weeks ago) Feature | Added  - Patryk 
| * ed2da1d - (45 minutes ago) Feature | Added - S (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
| * d580796 - (2 hours ago) Fix | Tag - W 
| * e0b1611 - (2 hours ago) Fix - S
| * 8588818 - (2 weeks ago) Documentation | Incremented documentation version - X
|/  
* 05ff79b - (2 weeks ago) Fix | changed structure - M
```

But as you can see this is not chronological - namely, the branches give straight lines instead of showing that the commits in e.g. 2 branches have happened chronologically (e.g. `ed2da1d` should be on the top of the log).

How can I make that chronological? (for instance GitLab has some kind of this log that show chronological commits in multiple branches but in its web UI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on the behavior it looks like giving an explicit date format lights `--topo-order`. That's weird, but explicitly giving `--date-order` fixes it for me.